# Letting JAVA program memorize the generated random number

Tags: java, random

I have a program that generates a random number between 1 and n.

Let's say n = 6.

I let the program generate 7 numbers and got the following:
3,4,3,1,2,3,6

How can I let the program **Store**  *the numbers generated* AND *how many times* every number has been generated. The answer will be like this:

3 came up 3 times.

4 came up 1 time.

1 came up 1 time.

6 came up 2 times.

Comment: What do you mean **memorizes**?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  You are expected to attempt a solution to the homework problem yourself and show what you have done _before_ asking for help.  SO is not a "do my homework for me" site.  If you have no idea where to start, you should be talking to your teacher.

Comment: You really need to put some effort in. This is trivial and does not deserve to be asked here let alone answered!

Comment: @azurefrog While nonstandard terminology, I really think the meaning is very clear from the context.

Comment: I have a program called Roulette. It generates a random number is see if it matches mine. I have 500 chips and can play until I have not. The exact thing I want to do is: "For each number that was the result of a spin, how many times that number was the result of a spin."

Comment: @user3378151 Thank you for editting the post!

Answer (score 1):

```
int one=0;

int two=0;

int three=0;

int four=0;

int five=0;

int six=0;

int myRandomNumber = yourRandomizerMethod();

    switch (myRandomNumber) {
        case 1:  one++;
                 break;
        case 2:  two++;
                 break;
        case 3:  three++;
                 break;
        case 4:  four++;
                 break;
        case 5:  five++;
                 break;
        case 6:  six++;
                 break;
    }
```

Comment: Ever heard of an array?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many times the user will repeat the process or what is the n value (maximum number).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I let the program Store the numbers generated AND how many
>   times every number has been generated?

*I should not give you direct program.*

Think about following.

- Java is all about OOP
- You need to store `Counter` and `Value` so find Something about `Collection Framework`
- You have to `Iterate` through content you have stored.
- After finding If number Exist Increment Counter and if Not add new with `Counter=1`.

Now what to use for this purpose.

You may find [CollectionFrameWork](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm) tutorial interesting to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Store each number in a map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numberCounts = new HashMap<>();

    int n = 7;
    int limit = 100;
    Map<Integer, Integer> numberCounts = new HashMap<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        int randNum = random.nextInt(limit);

        Integer count = numberCounts.get(randNum);
        if (count == null) {
            count = Integer.valueOf(1);
        } else {
            count = count.intValue() + 1;
        }

        numberCounts.put(randNum, count);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : numberCounts.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " came up " 
                + entry.getValue() + ((entry.getValue() > 1) ? " times" : " time"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will go and read about this method. I am a newbie and have not taken this in the course.

Comment: This helps a lot! I have finish my program with the help of your coding. However, I still need to figure out how to come up with the lase for loop. thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by "lase" for the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash map.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

When you generate your random number you can check if it in your map of previous numbers and if it's not then you add it and associate it to 1. If it's in your map then you increment the count.

```
Integer n = map.get(generatedRandomNumber);
if(n == null) {
    n = new Integer(1);
} else {
    n = n.add(1);
}
map.put(generatedRandom, n);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea! Btw, can I use the hash map if I don't now the numbers generated, maximum number, and how many times the process was repeated?

Comment: Sure, there are no restrictions as to the values you put as keys in the HashMap as long as they are objects of type Integer and are not  null.